# How to execute two promises but return response after the first one is done

Tags: node.js

I need to execute two promises (e.g. to save a document e.g. on Cloudant no really matter). But I need to send http response right after first promise complete and don't wait for another one. For now we don't care if another promise is success or fail. Here is what I do:

```
  let promise1 = saveDocument(data1);
  let promise2 = saveDocument(data2);

  promise1
  .then((response) => {
    promise2.then().catch();

    resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    resp.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(err.message))
  })
```

or it's not the right approach? Here is the original code:

```
  promise1
  .then((response) => {
    promise2.then((response) => {
        resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response))
    }).
    .catch((err) => {
        resp.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(err.message))
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    resp.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(err.message))
  });
```

Comment: If you don't care about the response from promise2 can't you just call function saveDocument(data2) and don't attach then() or catch() listeners.  If you don't care about the response there is no need to even save the response into promise2

Comment: The way you have the code written both promise will start at the same time when you use : `let promise2 = saveDocument(data2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it sounds like you only want to listen to the first promise and only fail if that one fails, the second can pass or fail on its own accord. If this is so your solution is pretty much there already.

```
let promise1 = saveDocument(data1);
let promise2 = saveDocument(data2);

promise1
  .then(response => {
    resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response))
  })
  .catch(err => {
    resp.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(err.message))
  })
```

Both promises will be started and both will reject or fail independently of each other but you are only listening to the result of promise1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). It resolves or rejects  as soon as one of the two promises resolves or rejects.

If you only want to resolve on the first successful promise, have a look at [bluebird's Promise.any](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) or write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What your're loking for is the [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/race) Api, so far I know is supported in all the browsers.

What you need is this:

```
let promise1 = saveDocument(data1);
let promise2 = saveDocument(data2);

// Both promises will be executed at the same time.
Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((response) => {
    // Both will be resolved, but the first one is the one that you get here.
    resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response))
});
```

I don't quite understand the logic of 500 and 200, but also can do this:

```
Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((response) => {
    // Only call if the first promise win.
    resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response))
}, (response) => {
    // Only call if the second promise win.
    resp.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(response))
});
```

In the second approach, you can have so many answers as promise you sen on the iterable of promises.

Hope this helps you!